# On copying a sheet, a warning mentions an undefined name range

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I'm attempting to save an Excel 2007 document I get an error saying:

> A formula or sheet you want to move or copy contains the name <...> which already exists on the destination worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Named Ranges can be hidden.
These named ranges do not appear in the named ranges manager.

To remove these named ranges, and thus solve the problem, save the document as an XML Workbook, remove the text lines which create the named ranges, then open the XML file, and save as an XSLX file.